# How to publish/push Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I know how to publish/push docker image but I'm completely thrown off on how one can publish `Dockerfile`. For e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/node/~/dockerfile/

Currently, I'm pushing images with the following command:-

`docker push myusername/myimage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pushing/publishing `Dockerfile` is actually called "Automating Builds" which you simply push it to either github or bitbucket. And after you link your github repo which has `Dockerfile` it will show up automatically. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/)